UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x7f1bf15c6520> i am getting this error when i am trying to run this code
!pip install pdf2image
!pip install pytesseract
!apt-get install poppler-utils
!apt-get update
!pip install -U langchain-community
!pip install unstructured -q
!pip install unstructured[local-inference] -q
!pip install detectron2@git+https://github.com/facebookresearch/detectron2.git@v0.6#egg=detectron2 -q
from langchain_community.document_loaders import  DirectoryLoader
directory = '/content/drive/MyDrive/content/data'
loader = DirectoryLoader(directory)
documents = loader.load()
print(f"Number of documents loaded: {len(documents)}")
i have tried to run this last piece of code to load the documents but it is not loading it says
unidentfiedimageerror :The traceback indicates that there was an UnidentifiedImageError raised by the Pillow library. This typically occurs when the library cannot interpret the image data format. In this case, the error arises during the PDF to image conversion process, where pdf2image is likely producing image data that Pillow cannot decode. This could be due to a variety of reasons, such as an outdated Pillow library or corrupted PDF files.
i have tried everthing can anyone help me out pleasee!!!

Does this happen for all PDFs with embedded bitmap images or only some?
